# Arduino write String to serial

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to write `String` to serial in `arduino` ,

The string has multiple data types :

```
String sendID=("alarmWithPointer:" + String(12,DEC) ) ;//AlarmOncePointer
```

and `Serial.write(sendID)` **gives error**, so i tried :

```
 void sendDataSerial(String data)
 {

    int len=data.length()+1;
     char buf[len];
     data.toCharArray(buf, len) ;
     Serial.write(buf);

 }
```

Which also gives random numbers in the serial .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [Serial.Print()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/print) (ASCII characters) instead of [Serial.Write()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/write) (binary data)?